# Getting data out of Typo3

Tags: typo3

We have a site we're taking over and porting from typo3 to Orchard.  As of right now, all we have is the database and none of the site files. I have the database setup on mysql and can query the data.  I don't currently know what version of typo3 it's using.  If necessary, I might be able to find out, but as I said, right now all I have is the database.

I need to get the data out in a usable form so that I can massage it into the xml needed to import into Orchard.  The problem is, I can't find any documentation on how typo3's database is setup, so I've not been able to get at the content...thus far, the only useful table I've found is the "pages" table, but that really seems to just store the instance of a page, minus the content.  Here are the things I need:

```
Page Title
Parent Page (for hierarchical concerns)
Content for a page
```

Can someone shed some light onto what tables I need to look for to pull this content out?

- Edit *
  I was able to get something working using:

What I did was gather the data using this query:

```
select p.Uid PageId, p.pid ParentId, Title, c.BodyText, concat('index.php?id=',p.Uid) OriginalUrl,
p.deleted, c.deleted
from pages p
left join tt_content c on p.Uid = c.Pid
where p.deleted = 0 and c.deleted = 0
```

And then going through each of the tt_content records and concatenating them together to flatten and form somewhat coherent HTML for a page...this is better than nothing.   I haven't done anything with the plugins yet, but I do see tx_ tables in there...regardless, this is a start...
order by PageId, c.pid

Comment: After searching all morning, I decided to post this question to SO.  After posting it, I went back and looked at the db, and apparently there's a tt_content table that I missed completely.  I'll look into this...in the meantime, if anyone else has anything to add, please let me know.

Comment: **pages** table contains all the pages, **tt_content** table contains all the content of the pages. However, I'm afraid you will soon run into one problem: the content saved in the database is not the same as the one outputted by TYPO3. There are transformations going on that you would have to apply to get the correct HTML output as produced by the original TYPO3 website.

Comment: Serious? So, is there any way to know how to apply these transformations, or is there a better way to get the data out?  If I were able to get an instance of the website up and running, is there an export feature in there?

Comment: There is an export feature in TYPO3. It would even export the records in XML but it's still gonna be the internal form of the content as saved in the database instead of the HTML output of the pages in the frontend. It's all about what exactly you need. If you want the content in the exact form as it was outputted in the frontend, consider grabbing it by spidering the website with some of the many applications available instead of trying to decode how TYPO3 produces the output from what's in the database.

Comment: i forgot: tt_content.colPos indicates in which column the content was. If there are different values for colPos, you should order by colPos and then sorting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datebase structure is pretty simple. You have the pages table which has a uid and a pid. The pid allways defines on which page a record is created.

```
Page Title => pages.title
Parent Page (for hierarchical concerns) => pages.pid
Content for a page => tt_content.* where pid = pages.pid order by sorting
```

There are different types of pages, some of them are just folders which holds records, but the page does not exist in the menu.

The same is with tt_content. There are a lot of different Content Elements (like Text, Image, Text/Image, Headers etc.). Have a look at tt_content.CType for that. It can happen, that you have an image defined, but someone changed the content element to TEXT only, so the image will not be rendered in TYPO3. You need to have a look at colPos too. This field indicates in which column the content will be shown. colPos = 0 is usally the normal column, colPos = 1 left, colPos = 2 right etc. But it depends. Within these columns you can use sorting to get the correct order.

Beside tt_content there are "plugins" or "extensions" which ships with additional tables. The usually start with tx_ or tt_. So, they will hold records too.

It would be possible to render the XML you need for each page with TYPO3 - without any template. The database would be enough. But for that you need to understand TypoScript and the TYPO3 database scheme. I guess, you will be fine with getting the pure data.

There are some additional fields, but imho the important ones are pretty easy to understand: deleted = 0/1, hidden = 0/1, starttime, endtime, uid, pid.

Comment: To make things a bit harder, there might be translations and workspaces used. Here are some links to documentation (sorry for the temp URLs, but the real documentation is so dam slow) http://srv123.typo3.org/~mbless/DOCROOT_HTDOCS/TYPO3v4/doc_core_inside/html/02/02-06/02-06-02-Relational_Database_Structure.html and http://srv123.typo3.org/~mbless/DOCROOT_HTDOCS/TYPO3v4/doc_core_inside/html/02/02-07/02-07-01-Versioning_in_TYPO3.html and maybe http://srv123.typo3.org/~mbless/DOCROOT_HTDOCS/TYPO3v4/doc_core_tca/html/

Comment: Thank you kindly...we'll just use the raw data for now and someone will have to fix the content later...